# How can I get a reference to a google cloud storage bucket inside my cloud function?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to replicate the guide [Example: image transformation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#example_image_transformation).

I'm ok until I need to call:

```
import * as gcs from '@google-cloud/storage';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const onFileChange = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(object => {

  // this line throws a TypeScript Error
  const destBucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
  ...
}
```

> Property 'bucket' does not exist on type 'typeof Storage'. Did you mean 'Bucket'?

I also tried:

```
const destBucket = new gcs.Bucket(new gcs.Storage({}), object.bucket);
```

this compiles but when executing I get an error:

> gcs.Storage is not a constructor

It seems as if the API has changed, but I'm updated to the latest versions:

```
"@google-cloud/storage": "^1.6.0",
"firebase-functions": "^1.0.2",
```

**How can I get a reference to the Bucket so that I can call?:**

```
destBucket
    .file(filePath)
    .download({ destination: tempFilePath })
    .then(() => { ... })
```

Comment: Note that since the release of Version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions, there are some changes in the parameters of most of the triggers:

For Storage it has now to be as follow:

`exports.processFile = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object, context) => {`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#storage. However I've tried with you code and `const destBucket = gcs.bucket(....);` still works (which somehow makes sense since it is not linked to object). How do you declare gcs?

Comment: `import * as gcs from '@google-cloud/storage';` I also have the argument `context`, but removed it to simplify the example.

Comment: Look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you declared gcs with a config object like:

```
const config = {
    projectId: '....',
    keyFilename: './.......-adminsdk-0vlsn-34c393497c.json'
};

const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')(config);
```

You have to use a service-key.json generated in Firebase, as explained in this Cloud Functions official sample https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail

"Go to the Firebase Console, select the gear image > project settings > Service Accounts and click Generate New Private Key to download a Service Account Key JSON document."

---

In addition the error message most probably means that you have to create an instance of Storage.

Comment: I don't think the config arguments were an issue, but I was not invoking the root method. instead I was using `import * as gcs from '@google-cloud/storage';` Is there a typescript was to invoke an import?

Comment: @NateMay What do you lean by "Is there a typescript was to invoke an import"?

Comment: something like `import * as gcs() from '@google-cloud/storage';` similar to `const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();`

Comment: You are using Vue.js, angular, or another framework?

Comment: well, my application project is Angular, how can that impact my cloud functions imports?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, indeed, because actually in a Cloud Function you don't have to import this way, so I thought it was in a front end framework. I don't know how you could initialize it through an import statement in CF.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and this is how I did it:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as path from 'path'
import * as os from 'os'
import * as child_process from 'child_process'
import * as fs from 'fs'

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const resizePhoto = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => {

   const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);

.....
```