# Specifying the bucket in a Google Cloud Logging query in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, query-optimization, google-cloud-logging

## My Problem

I am using GCL to store activity events for items in a system. Each event is stored as a separate log line, and when I want to see the activity history of a specific item I query GCL using its TS Library:

```
const filter = `logName="some-log-name" AND jsonPayload.itemId="${itemId}" AND timestamp >= "2023-07-01T00:00:00Z"`;
    const options = {
        autoPaginate: false,
        filter: filter,
        pageSize: 1000,
        orderBy: 'timestamp desc',
    };
    console.log(options, itemId);
    try {
        const [entries] = await logging.getEntries(options);
        return entries.map(entry => entry.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching logs:', error);
        return [];
    }
```

The fields are properly indexed:

```
$ gcloud logging buckets describe activity-logs-prod-us  --location global --project=c-cloud-environment
createTime: '2023-06-28T07:41:16.899404569Z'
description: Activity logs prod prod us env
indexConfigs:
- createTime: '2023-07-25T11:24:05.142048279Z'
  fieldPath: jsonPayload.itemId
  type: INDEX_TYPE_INTEGER
- createTime: '2023-07-25T11:24:05.142048279Z'
  fieldPath: jsonPayload.logType
  type: INDEX_TYPE_STRING
lifecycleState: ACTIVE
name: projects/c-cloud-environment/locations/global/buckets/activity-logs-prod-us
retentionDays: 3650
updateTime: '2023-07-25T11:24:05.142048279Z'
```

**Unfortunately, the response takes 15-20 seconds for small data sets of a few hundred thousand items.**

## What Have I Tried

I suspect that the problem is related to indexing, or to the fact that I have a lot of data in other GCL buckets. I tried specifying the bucket to search in, but could not find this option.

## My Question

How can I specify the bucket in a GCL query, to avoid searching all the buckets?

Answer (score 0):

To specify the bucket, you need to specify a LogView in that bucket as the resource name to query in the ListLogEntries query.

When you are calling `logging.getEntries(options)`, the `options` is a [`GetEntriesRequest`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/blob/14f9853a4017fa291b53524377fd0c7aa67b56dd/src/log.ts#L610)

There is a [`resourceNames`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/blob/14f9853a4017fa291b53524377fd0c7aa67b56dd/src/log.ts#L48) field you can set in the options.

This `resourceNames` can either take in a project-id or a LogView name. You can use a view name that looks like:

`projects/[PROJECT_ID]/regions/[REGION]/buckets/[BUCKET_ID]/views/[VIEW_ID]`

See the full documentation of the API [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list).

Answer (score -1):

You can try to [include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781405/cannot-import-google-storage-in-typescript)

```
import * as gcs from '@google-cloud/storage';
const storage = new gcs.Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketname);
```

or

```
const destBucket = gcs.bucket(....);
```

If it still [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036513/how-can-i-get-a-reference-to-a-google-cloud-storage-bucket-inside-my-cloud-funct/50038863#50038863).

Comment: Note that Cloud Logging buckets and GCS storage buckets are different things.